# htaccess / mod_expires - caching specific files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, mod-expires

Ok, I checked a lot of websites about how to manage the browser's cache memory with a `.htaccess` file, but it is still very not clear to me.

I want to cache specific files for one month. For the rest, I want it to be refreshed every time. So I tried:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c> 
    Header unset Cookie
    Header unset Set-Cookie
    Header unset Cache-Control
    Header unset ETag
    FileETag none 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>  
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "now"
    <Files "/css/jquery-ui.css">
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    </Files>
    <Files "/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    </Files>
    <Files "/js/jquery-ui.js">
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    </Files>
    <Files "/js/analytics.js">
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    </Files>
    <Files "/matheos/img/*">
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    </Files>
    <Files "/img/*">
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work exactly as expected...

The HTML is correctly not cached, but the specific files like `jquery-ui.css`, which should be cached for 1 month, are also not cached.

Anyway, does this `.htaccess` seem ok for you ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, got it ! To target a specific file, the correct syntax is :

```
# to not cache css except jquery-ui.css
ExpiresByType text/css "now"
<FilesMatch "jquery-ui\\.css$">
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
```

This is the only way that worked for me, at least in the case of an ovh shared host. I also tried all possible combinations with `ExpiresDefault` but it didn't work...

Comment: Why add two backslashes in the middle of the css file's path? Is that an escape character unique to htaccess files?

Comment: Yes, because the dot is a special character in regex

Comment: you don't need the double escape http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch